# Simplifying sum of binomial coefficients $\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}{8S+1 \choose j}$ where $S$ is a half-integer

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I'd like to simplify the following sum:

> $$\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}{8S+1 \choose j},$$

where $S\in\{1/2,1,3/2,2,5/2,\ldots\}$ and $\ m,n\in\{1,3,5,7,9,\ldots,4S-1\}$. By simplifying I mean expressing the sum as a single term (or a few), if possible.

I've found a bunch of identities that *almost* solves it, but not quite. Here are some other forms of the sum:

$\displaystyle\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}{8S+1 \choose j}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}{8S+1 \choose 8S+1-j}$

$=\displaystyle\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}(-1)^{j}{j-8S-2 \choose j}=\displaystyle\sum_{j=m+n+1}^{8S+1}(-1)^{j}{j-8S-2 \choose -8S-2}$.

The upper limit can be taken to $\infty$ and a promising identity is $\sum_{j=0}^{8S+1}{8S+1 \choose j}=2^{8S+1}.\ $ Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general,
you are looking for an expression for
$f(n, m) =\sum_{k=m}^n \binom{n}{k}$.

I don't believe there is such a formula.

There are special cases,
such as when $m$ is a small constant
or when $m = \lfloor \frac{n}{2} \rfloor$,
but, in general,
I think you are out of luck.

Also,
the expression $m+n+1$
just takes on all odd values
from $1$ to $8S-1$,
so I don't see the point in it.

Also$^2$,
I don't see why
"the upper limit can be taken to
$\infty$"
unless you divide the sum by
$2^{8S+1}$
and then take the limit.
*Then*
you might be able to do something,
but you would have to consider how
$\frac{m+n+1}{8S+1}$
behaves as
$S \to \infty$.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right. What I meant with the limit to $\infty$ was that the binomial coefficient equals zero when $j>8S+1$.

Comment: You mention a special case when $m$ is a small constant, what does this refer to? If it applies when $m=0$ it could be useful.